# windows 7 / server 2008 remote port query tool

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-7

Is there any built-in tool in Win7/Win Server 2008 to query remote host opening ports?

On Win XP/Win Server 2003, we can use `telnet <remote host> <port>` to do so. However, telnet is not available Win7/Win Server 2008.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to install `telnet` on 7/2008?

Comment: @TiZon, if there're tens of Win Server 2008, and keep adding. It would be better to use built-in tools, so the script won't break if new server doesn't have telnet installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a built-in tool. But 2003 shipped with `Prtqry.exe` a very handy tool to do just that. Maybe you could include it with the script or put it on a networkshare?

More info on can be found here : [KB310099](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310099)

Or if you have the rights to do it, run a `netstat` remotely.